# Question about specific kind of Video Game

Tags: game

assalamu alaykum

I work as 3D visualizer, visualizing architect's designs such as house/apartements, buildings etc.
Recently, i'm thinking about getting into video game industry as well. here is the idea of the game so far:
1. The video game will be cartoony, but in three dimensional shape. the characters will be humans, not realistic, big head, big eyes, with colorful hair.
2. the video game will basically about fishing, keeping fish, breeding them, selling them.
3. No music, just sound effects like wind, water splash etc.

here's my question:
1. Is it permissible if i make human character in 3d (cartoony, child-like, unrealistic body proportion) that can move, walk, interact, etc?
2. if the answer of 1st question is yes, then how about female character with exposed hair? ofcourse other body part will be covered, just the face, the hair, maybe arms. please note that the character shape will not resemble realistic adult body shape, its more like a child with cartoony proportion. in three dimensional form.
3. My game will be about fish, so i will create a 3d model of a cartoony fish that will be animated, like swimming, jumping, etc. is that permissible? how if i create a fish species that doesn't exist in the real world, lets say a common catfish but with unique yellow-black color. or even a completely new species of fish that doesnt exist in real world? is that permissible?
4. I will not include music in my game, but can i add a sound effect that have two or three musical note in it? like Do-Re-Mi or Mi-Do

I'm looking for the detailed answer, as i think this will be a big step in my life, and i don't want to make a wrong step.

Comment: As a game developer myself, I always wondered if I will be punished when folks miss their salaats due to playing my games and ignoring their religious obligations. W.r.t your question, I stay away from animate objects. Most of my games relate to racing and sports which help me avoid the gray area.